# How to understand non defined limits graphically

Tags: calculus, limits

I was recently introduced to the concepts of limits and I have a decent grasp on it however, I I think I still don’t have the right idea in my mind

For example :
[image]

How do I visual such a limit
I do understand that the two limits don’t meet at any point of the y axis basically there’s a hole I believe , howeverwhen I tried plotting a graph but I just don’t quite get what I just did :/

Here’s the plot i obtained
[image]

Comment: Hello , please feel free to suggest edits and all answers are welcomed

Comment: How exactly do you wish to visualise this? Is plotting the graph not sufficient?

Comment: So the hole is basically showing discontinity?

Comment: The graph does not have a hole in it. In mathematics, ‘hole’ has a precise meaning.

Comment: I’m sorry , I’m unaware of the terminology

Comment: I haven’t come across those terms yet, please excuse me and if u could give more info please do so

Comment: Saying that a function has a 'hole' at a certain point is generally a shorthand for saying it has a removable discontinuity (or removable singularity) there. I would suggest consulting a calculus textbook or online resource for more information.

Comment: Thanks a lot 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's called a jump discontinuity.  As $x$ approaches $1$ from the left, $f(x)$ approaches $0$, but as $x$ approaches $1$ from the right, $f(x)$ approaches $-2$.
A limit would require approaching the same number from both sides.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Be suspicious when dividing by zero or multiplying by infinity. That's often where discontinuities happen.

Here's some curves to view or discontinuity examples.

a) Jump discontinuities as above. Discontinuous because it has different left and right limits.

b) Infinity discontinuities like $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1}{x^2}=\infty$. Discontinuous because any open subset of the domain containing $0$ blows up too fast

[image: Infinity discontinuity]

c) Undefined, smooth functions with a missing point discontinuity like $\lim_{x\to 1} \frac{x^2-1}{x-1}=2$

[image: Undefined discontinuity]

d)Undefined essential discontinuities like $\lim_{x \to 0} \sin{(\frac{1}{x})}$

[image: Essential discontinuity]